# how to show variable ${number} instead of NaN

Tags: javascript

```
var number = Number(prompt('Type a number: '));
if (!isNaN(number))
    alert(`The square root of ${number} is ${number * number}`);
else
    alert(`${number} is not a number`);
```

how to show variable $ {number} instead of NaN in else structure

Comment: you can't show actual input through $ {number} variable because actual input is already converted to Number and that's why you are getting NaN instead of actual input. Use two variables instead, one to get user input and other to store Number object.

Answer (score 5):

Well you're not currently capturing what the user enters - only the result of trying to parse it numerically.

```
let input = prompt('Type a number'),
    number = Number(input);
if (!isNaN(number))
    alert(`The square root of ${number} is ${number * number}`);
else
    alert(`${input} is not a number`);
```

Also, your definition of square root is wrong; a square root is a number, X, which, when squared, gives the number Y. So your statement should read:

```
alert(`${number} is the square root of ${number * number}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = prompt('Type a number: ');
var number = Number(input);
if (!isNaN(number))
    alert(`The square root of ${number} is ${number * number}`);
else
    alert(`${input} is not a number`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = prompt('Type a number');
number = Number(input);
if (!isNaN(number))
    alert(`The square root of ${number} is ${Math.sqrt(number)}`);
else         
    alert(`${input} is not a number`);
```

In fact logically this is the answer. The math was wrong in the other answers!

Comment: It's not that the maths is wrong, it's that the OP's definition of square root was wrong. See the comment in my answer.